# Angular $http.post erroneously being invoked more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

EDIT:

I may have asked the wrong question. I simplified the Node.js code this morning and the issue stopped occurring. This issue seems related to use of the deasync module:

```
var done = false;
processGridCell(cell, layers, rowCount, colCount, datasetObject, function() { done = true});
deasync.loopWhile(function(){ return !done });
```

I would guess deasync was used to prevent the function from running out of memory. Each call to processGridCell saves a MongoDB document and it is called ~12,000 times. Because the main node thread never yields time to the async mongoose.save + callback the objects being saved are never GCed and the process runs out of memory.

I don't see an easy way out of using deasync. I also don't know why the use of deasync would cause another POST request from the client and why removing it would stop that request from occurring in the first place.

---

I have inherited a node/angular application that I've been charged with fixing up a bit.

What's happening is that when a form is submitted it invokes a Node.js function which takes 10-20 minutes to run. After a few minutes, while i can see that the Node function is still running, the same post request is submitted from the client a second time. I have not been able to root out the cause. Furthermore, I log information before the POST request is made, but it only logs the first time, not the second.

Here is the code, significantly abridged.

HTML:

```
<header class="text-center" data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'"></header>
<section>
    <div class="get-grid-form">
      <h2>Input Grid Size</h2>
        <hr>
      <form name="gridSizeForm" ng-controller="gridSizeCtrl" data-ng-submit="submitGridInput()" ng-class="{'has-error': gridSizeForm.myDecimal.$invalid}" >
        <div class="grid-input-form">

            <p>Other Irrelevent Content</p>

            <div class="get-grid-form-button" ng-show="!isLoading&&isCalculating&&!isError">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: auto; margin: 2px;">OK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="!isLoading" ng-click="cancel()"style="width: auto; margin: 2px;">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Angular:

```
angular.module('module').controller('gridSizeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload',
    '$http', '$window', '$stateParams', '$location',
    function ($scope,Upload,$http,$window,$stateParams,$location) 
{
    $scope.submitGridInput = function() {
        if ($scope.cellwidth === 'default') {
            units = 'kilometers';
            cellwidthval = 1;
        }

        $scope.upload( $scope.cellwidth, units, cellwidthval,
            $location.search()['param']);
    };

    $scope.upload = function (cellwidth,units,widthval, params) {
        $scope.isLoading = true;

        console.log("This only logs once. The second request fires without this logging")

        $http.post('/module/grid/create', 
        {  data:{someData: someData}
        }).success(function(response) 
        {   //success code
        }).error(function(response) 
        {   //error code
        });
    };
}
```

Node:

```
function moduleGridCreateFunction(req, res)
{
    try
    {
        mongoose.find(
        function(err)
        {
            mongoose.save(function(err)
            {
                mongoose.save(function(err)
                {
                    //etc. etc. etc. 
                    if(err)
                    { res.status(400).jsonp('some error'); }
                    else
                    {   //do thing that takes 10 minutes
                        res.status(200).jsonp('success');
                    }               
                });
            });
        });
    }
    catch(err)
    { res.status(400).jsonp('error'); }
}
```

Comment: Is there any sort of `httpInterceptor` in the app that triggers a new request if original times out?

Comment: I don't believe so. Though I'm not 100% sure where to look for it. The only place I see the text 'interceptor' is in my files is in the Angular.js files themselves.

Comment: if there is one (or more) It would be a factory as in : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Comment: I see `$stateParams` which suggests ui-router. My guess is the template is loaded and bound to the `gridSizeCtrl` via the state configuration. Using `ng-controller` in the template adds another controller instance. Don't use both. In fact, it's rare to see any valid use for `ng-controller`

Comment: @Phil, That doesn't appear to be the case. Removing the ng-controller causes the submit button to do nothing, so it likely cannot find the method. I'll be able to look more closely into this tomorrow.

Comment: It was worth looking into. Wouldn't be the first time mixing state configured controllers and `ng-controller` has caused problems

Comment: Check if you are loading angular more than once. This has caused duplicate firing of events for us in the past.

Comment: @alun I double checked, and I am sure that this was not the cause this time.

Comment: I believe the additional requests are a result of the browser continuing the request as specified here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4

Comment: But that does not explain why the subsequent requests stopped occurring when the deasync call was removed.